# Saving file with a name containing / at the destination folder in python

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am saving emails from outlook to the local folder.Folder path is following.

```
folder_path=r"C:\Documents\emails
```

filename is the subject of the email message as the following

```
subject=email_message.subject
```

so the final_path will be

```
final_path=os.path.join(folder_path,subject+".eml")
```

sometimes the subject contains "/" and then it gives the following error

```
[Error2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Documents\\emails\\test1/email_123'
```

I think this is because that extra "/" in the subject line (subject was "test1/email_123")

How can I fix this?

Comment: `subject.replace("/","-")` ?

Comment: when I do that the path becomes just too big and it gives the same error..it's only working when i choose couple of words in the subject that don't contain "/"

Comment: @TLanni strings are immutable. You'd have to create a new string and use it. `new_subject = subject.replace("/","-")`

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you want to treat the `/` in the subject line. Use the `.replace()` function on the subject accordingly.

**Ignore `/`**

`subject=email_message.subject.replace("/", "")`

Then the directory would be: 'C:\Documents\emails\test1email_123'

**Treat `/` as a directory structure**

`subject=email_message.subject.replace("/", "\")`

Then the directory would be: 'C:\Documents\emails\test1\email_123'

**Treat `/` as a special character**

If a `/` means something else in your organization like a hyphen or an underscore then use it.

`subject=email_message.subject.replace("/", "-")`

Then the directory would be: 'C:\Documents\emails\test1-email_123'

Answer (score 0):

you should replace the letter with something else.

like 'C:\Documents\emails\test1/email_123' should be converted into 'C:\Documents\emails\test1_email_123'

this can be done by putting one line before `final_path=os.path.join(folder_path,subject+".eml")`

```
subject.replace('/','_');
```